# Webhosting on a "Double NAT" network behind Altice One Gateway

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, nat

I have a home network with a small web-server hosted behind a LAN-WAN cascaded router. The port forwarding rules on my Altice One router point traffic on port 8080 to my cascaded routers port 8080 which then forwards it to web-server. This works fine from the WAN but loopback from the primary LAN fails. I'm new to this type of network, are there any solutions?

[image]

Comment: google "hairpinning". Your router needs to support that.

Comment: @Tetsujin I can't seem to find much information about whether the Altice One supports it but I can loopback successfully from LAN2 which seems to indicate that it does have support. Additionally running nslookup from a device on the primary LAN shows that the DNS is resolving to the correct WAN address